# Correct Syntax for referencing a schema with a space in the name

Tags: sql, psycopg2, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

So I am writing a python script to take some data from PGAdmin4 via psycopg2.
Below is a snippet that relates to running the SQL query. There are no errors with connecting to the database.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
#query to retrieve from table
CD_Retrieve = "select * from Schema Name" #something wrong with this


#executes query
cursor.execute(CD_Retrieve) 

print("Selecting rows from Schema Name")
CD_Records = cursor.fetchall()

#for loop to display all records
for row in CD_Records:
    print(row[0])
```

I've tried accessing a schema that does not have a space in the name and it performs just fine.

I have tried running the query within the query tool of pgAdmin4. It suggests using quotation marks. However it returns an error saying that the schema does not exist. Ive also tried several other charcaters such as: [], {}, '', ,``

How do I reference a schema name that has a space in it within pgAdmin4?

Comment: Simply avoid <space> in object names, and you'll never have this issue again.

Comment: In SQL, double quotes are used to delimit identifiers, e.g. `"Schema name"`.

Comment: I would love to, However the company I am working with is being very difficult about it, due to the various things that access the table :)

Comment: @jarlh If you read the question you would know that it responds with an error saying the schema does not exist :)

Comment: Check the casing as well - double quotes will preserve case, so `"Schema Name"` will not match `"schema name"`.  A point on nomenclature: in PostgreSQL, a schema is a collection of tables within a database, so it isn't something that would be queried directly like a table or view.  But you might qualify a table name with a schema like `SELECT * FROM "Schema Name".mytable`.